# Matlab - making a MEX, Coder cannot classify defined field of a struct array

Tags: matlab, struct, mex, matlab-coder

The MATLAB Coder has proven very helpful to me recently, successfully making a MEX file of a function with `parfor` in it, wonderfully speeding up a long-running program.
However, I just added another line to the code, and Coder is telling me it can't classify a variable in that line:

```
if any(bullseyes)
    firstHit = bullseyes(1);
    organism(x,y).path(firstHit).hit = targ;
    targsHit = targsHit + 1;
    targsTouched = targsTouched + 1;
end
```

I hover the mouse over the word `hit`, at the end of `organism(x,y).path(firstHit).hit`, and it tells me `A variable in a parfor could not be classified`. (This is indeed inside a `parfor`, indeed it's in a `for` within that `parfor`, but since there is so much inside the `parfor`, I decided only to share this much.) It may be helpful to know that `bullseyes` is redefined every iteration of the `for` loop containing this `if` and a little more, `y` and `x` are the counter variables for the `parfor` loop and the `for` loop containing it, respectively, and `targsHit` and `targsTouched` are placeholder variables that transfer their cargo at the end of each x,y combination.

I am surprised that it's not recognizing the class of `organism.path.hit` for two reasons. In another, nearly identical, block of code that follows this one, the equivalent call `organism(x,y).path(firstGlance).hit = targ;` gets no objection - though I imagine the interface might be programmed to only object to the first instance of an error when fixing one fixes them all. Also, more significantly, I already told Coder what that field is classified as, on the previous page of the interface. As you can see in the image below, it should recognize this as a double scalar:
[image: Enter Input Types]
Any thoughts on why this definition is not going through, and how I might make Coder understand that this scalar field of a struct field of a struct, being defined within a `parfor` loop, is a scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is "A variable in a parfor could not be classified" is referring to the classification of variables used in parfor loops mentioned on the following documentation page :

http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/classification-of-variables-in-parfor-loops.html

The access

organism(x,y).path(firstHit).hit

does not match any of the classifications mentioned on that page. Therefore it is not supported for use within a parfor loop in MATLAB Coder. You could try rewriting the parfor loop in a way that all variable usages match the classifications described in the link. If anything cannot be written to match a classification it can be moved outside the parfor loop.

Variable usages matching these classifications are needed to ensure that different iterations of the loop can be executed on parallel threads.